# An overview of fungible Ethereum Token standards/proposals?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-223, erc-677

Beside the well known EIP-20, we have a number of other proposals for fungible tokens. Each of them addressing a different set of requirements.

**[Q]** Is there an overview of fungible Token standards/proposals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine recently published a well received blog post on this topic. In his blog post, he describes and compares the following standards/proposals with each other:

- EIP-20
- EIP-150
- ERC-223
- ERC-677
- ERC-777

http://blockchainers.org/index.php/2018/02/08/token-erc-comparison-for-fungible-tokens/

> The current state of Token standards on the Ethereum platform is
>   surprisingly simple: ERC-20 Token Standard is the only accepted and
>   adopted (as EIP-20) standard for a Token interface.
>
> Proposed in 2015, it has finally been accepted at the end of 2017.
>
> In the meantime, many Ethereum Requests for Comments (ERC) have been
>   proposed which address shortcomings of the ERC-20, which partly were
>   caused by changes in the Ethereum platform itself, eg. the fix for the
>   re-entrancy bug with EIP-150. Other ERC propose enhancements to the
>   ERC-20 Token model. 
>   [...]
>   This blogpost should give a superficial, but complete, overview of all
>   proposals for Token(-like) standards on the Ethereum platform.